# Deducion of the new length at temperature $T+\Delta T$ for a metal band

Tags: thermodynamics

I would like to deduce that for a metal strip if the coefficient of thermal expansion ($\beta$) is constant then for a temperature increase $ \Delta T $ the new length will be $l\approx l_0(1+\beta\Delta T)$

But I'm a little bit stuck. On another book says that $l=l_0e^{\beta\Delta T}$
so it's easy for me to go from there to what I want to prove if I take only the first two terms of the taylor series of the exponential function

since $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cfrac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\cfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$

then $l_0e^{\beta\Delta T}=l_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cfrac{(\beta\Delta T)^n}{n!}=l_0\left(1+\beta\Delta T+\cfrac{(\beta\Delta T)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)\approx l_0(1+\beta\Delta T)$

From the definition we can know that the coefficient of thermal expansion at constant tension of a metal strip is

$\beta=\cfrac{1}{l}\left(\cfrac{\partial l}{\partial T}\right)_\tau$
where $\tau$ is the tension on the belt and  $ l$ its length. And at temperature $T$ the length is $l_0$.

So if $\beta=\cfrac{1}{l}\left(\cfrac{\partial l}{\partial T}\right)_\tau=\text{constant}$

How can I deduce the equality $l=l_0e^{\beta\Delta T}$ ?
So that you can apply Taylor to already get the desired result.

I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from
$$\beta=\frac{1}{l}\left( \frac{\partial l}{\partial T} \right)_\tau$$

or
$$\beta=\frac{1}{l}\frac{dl}{dT}$$
$$\frac{dl}{l}=\beta dT$$
or
$$\int_{l_0}^{l}\frac{dl}{l}=\beta \int_{T_0}^{T_0+\Delta T} dT$$
$$\ln l-\ln l_0=\beta (T_0+\Delta T-T_0)$$
or
$$l=l_0 e^{\beta \Delta T}$$
QED :)

Comment: Please note that I use the fact $\beta$ is constant to make partial derivative to ordinary differential.